# Architecture to upload files via API gateway

Tags: amazon-s3, networking, file-upload, proxy, api-gateway

I am working on designing a system to upload files to the server. The request to upload a file must go through the API gateway. The request will be a REST API POST request and the request body is a file type form-data (ie. the location of the file to upload). The upload of a single file should be replicated on a quorum of file servers. For eg., if I have 3 file servers, the client should get acknowledged of successful upload after the file has been written to at least 2 file servers. The actual file upload (data transfer) should happen directly between the client and the file servers and not through the API gateway (or any proxy server in the path).

My Solution -  API gateway returns the list of file servers(URL) to write and the client library orchestrates the uploads and makes sure that the upload happens of a quorum of file servers. But this creates a thick client which contains all the orchestration logic and is hard to maintain for different languages.

Is there any better way to solve this? How is this done in production servers? For eg, AWS S3/Azure blob store or any other production-grade system must be sending the request to API gateway(or proxy) first, how are they handling this?

Comment: There are a couple of things that aren't clear. It doesn't look like file servers are not serving from S3 service. You made it clear that client should upload directly to the file server. Then what is the involvement of S3 here? I have other questions but they do depend on the answer to this question so I'll wait the answer first.

Comment: @EthanDoh: Thanks for the response. Files will be serviced by the file servers. There is no involvement of the S3 or Azure blob store here. It was just a follow question on how these services are handling requests.

Comment: Then does the file server has web server or any other services to receive the file directly?

Comment: @EthanDoh The file is received directly from the end-user(for eg.  a laptop). There is no service to receive files. The end-user will use the REST API client (POST/PUT request) to upload files from the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to build a serverless solution which I'm not expert on.

One way I can think of is to use S3 bucket as a proxy (I know you said no proxy server but somehow did mention S3 ‍♂️) storage server. You can then setup Lambda service to act on S3 upload complete. That Lambda function will then be responsible to upload S3 object to whichever file servers that will be hosting the uploaded file.

At least this way, the client only needs to concern with uploading file one time. If the client needs to check to see if at least 2 file servers have the file, you can poll using HEAD request since you would have endpoint urls with the initial request.

I'm not sure if this is a workable solution for you. If not, hopefully someone with more experience on the serverless architect can give you better answer.